# What model to use for regressing a percentage against a percentage?

Tags: regression, percentage

If I have a response variable and independent variable that are both percentages, should I use a log-log linear model?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the response variable?  Is it a count of successes measured against a number of trials (e.g. number of heads observed from a coin flip) or is it a percentage of something continuous divided by something continuous (e.g. the mass of white blood cells per volume of blood)

Comment: percentage is basically a scaled version of the data, while assuming a log-log linear models puts an assumption on the relation between variables. so it is completely possible that the underlying data distribution calls for log models or linear models. It is independent of the scaling of the data